# Tag 'source' seems to be pointless

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked a question and added the tag [source-code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/source-code) but only typed `source` to get it. I then noticed that the tag [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/source) exists, it has 83 questions and no wiki - should it be deleted?

No questions should have this tag, any question tagged with this can be changed to be tagged with [source-code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/source-code) or [software-sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-sources) or [install-from-source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/install-from-source) instead.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, source and source-code, doesn't make any sense in the site. I've checked out some questions with both tags and saw, pretty much software installation, compilation, make questions. No questions about "source code" itself.

Software Sources is a GUI application to manipulate the sources.list:

> GUI-based repository management is normally accomplished via "Software Sources". This interface can be accessed via several methods. For the latest versions of Ubuntu, the easiest way is to go through the "Ubuntu Software Center". Open the software center, then from the Edit menu select "Software Sources".

(source https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

This is entire different to what "sources" or "source code" wants to mean.

[install-from-sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/install-from-sources) seems like a subset of software installation. Answerers rarely cares if you want to install something from sources or the compiled binary. From sources it may involve extra steps (the infamous `./configure && make`) but in essence all questions about installing something from sources are installing software. No need to fragment anymore the topic.